# Creating Custom Keyboard Layouts for Windows RT

Tags: keyboard-layout, windows-rt, microsoft-klc

How can I create my own keyboard layout for my Surface RT?

For non-ARM devices, [MSKLC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) does exactly that, but it cannot target Windows RT.

Comment: @Ramhound: MSKLC is not an irrelevant tag.

Answer (score 0):

I tried by making a keyboard programmatically inside my application using a child control and loading it on tapped function.

If you are looking for something global then , you can try this
http://www.ghacks.net/2010/06/06/the-ultimate-guide-to-keyboard-remapping/

Comment: Almost none of that will work on Windows RT.

Comment: Are u looking for a new layout for on a global scale or just for an app ?

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would contain no real information.  In general, the essential information should be included within your answer and the link used for attribution and further reading.  In this case, though, the link isn't useful, so you might want to just delete the answer.  Link-only answers tend to attract downvotes.